# What command to use for FirstLogonCommand Synchronous command in autounattend to install an application from the thumb drive

Tags: xml, powershell, cmd

What command and/or powershell command do I use in the FirstLogonCommands in the autounattend file to install a program located on the thumb drive after first logon?

I tried powershell commands

```
Start-Process -FilePath "e:folder\filename.exe" -Verb runAs -ArgumentList '/s','/v"/qn"'
```

`Start-Process e:folder\filename.exe /S -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru`
but can't get these to work.

edit:
`E:\temp\program.exe /s /v` runs the program but how do I call the drive itself regardless of what drive letter is assigned??

edit:edit

found this on https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/70784a32-7037-4e73-8129-4cea17d1a803/place-script-on-usbstick-with-autounattendxml-on-it-and-execute-as-firstlogoncommand?forum=win10itprogeneral

```
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RunSynchronous>
      <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
        <Order>1</Order>
        <Description>Set InstallDrive environment variable</Description>
        <Path>cmd /c FOR %i IN (C D E F G H I J K L N M O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO IF EXIST %i:\InstallDrive.tag SETX InstallDrive %i:\ -m</Path>
    </RunSynchronousCommand>
  </RunSynchronous>
</component>
```

Comment: Seems bold to assume it will be e:  - can you give more detail what you’re talking about?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am trying to install a program (logmein) on first logon. I can either place the  installer in the image file (wim) and call the program from c:\temp (& it deletes itself) or set it up in the firstlogon commands in unattend.. but I don't know what drive letter will be assigned to the bootable jumpdrive